# Sort the data as it enters into the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have a sheet which is populated by another sheet and in the populated sheet i want to do an automatic sort in an ascending order but every time data enter, i sorts even my columns and the values i don't want it to sort as below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

i want it it sort column AK starting from cell AK3 while excluding X which are just there to keep the cells. The data which is (DIV 3,DIV 2,DIV 1,DIV 4) is picked from another worksheet. I want it to sort beginning with DIV 1 to DIV 4,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK:AK")) Is Nothing Then
With ThisWorkbook
Range("AK1").Sort Key1:=Range("AK3"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is my vba code

Comment: Why do you show the sorting way **you do not want** and not show to us what you want? I cannot see any (,DIV 2,DIV 1,DIV 4) you mention only in words. What do you mean by "X which are just there to keep the cells"? Do you want that cell to be on bottom of the sorted range? Now, what "is populated by another sheet" does mean? Are there formulas, or an event will populate it in code?

Comment: am using two sheets, where sheet one has all the data and sheet two picks only specific data from sheet one, thus sheet one populates sheet two. In sheet one there is DIV1 , DIV 2, DIV 3, DIV 4  but what i want is that when it reaches in sheet two, DIV 1 is always on the top followed by DIV 2 ,DIV 3 and DIV 4 no matter the way the data looks like but the arrangement should be that excluding empty cells

Comment: What does "picks only specific data from sheet one" mean? I asked you if the mentioned population way is done **by formula** or in a different way. According to your answer a specific event should be used...

Comment: the population is done by a formular, which looks like so =IFERROR(SYSTEMDATA!AF2,"")

Comment: Then, `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered. You must use `Calculate` event...

Comment: how can i write that code please

Comment: I will post an answer in two minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Please, copy the next event code instead of the existing one (`Worksheet_Change`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim lastR As Long
   lastR = Me.Range("C" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   With Me
    .Range("AK3:AK" & lastR).Calculate
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo NiceEnding
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=.Range("AK3:AK" & lastR), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
                .SetRange Me.Range("A3:AK" & lastR)
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
        End With
    End With
NiceEnding:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The above event is triggered by any formula result change, which triggers the `Calculate` event.

If you really need/want to do the job only if changes are done in "AK:AK" column, a `Private` array variable will keep all values of the respective range and when the event is triggered the column cells are compared with the array values and the sorting is executed only if any cell value has been changed. Then the new values in that column are loaded in the reference array. But, in such a case sorting will not do anything, keeping existing order...

Comment: @Intel Power Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: your code will be triggered automatically by  `Calculate event` ,So I do not understand the using of `With Me .Calculate`

Comment: @Waleed `Calculate` event is triggered when a single cell having a formula (in any sheet) is modified. According to such cells with formulas number, calculations may take tens of seconds. The event **is not triggered after all cells have been updated**. So `Me.Calculate` obliges the code to wait until all cells **in the respective sheet** have been calculated. Otherwise, the sorting may take place before all necessary cells to be modified were updated. If you copy somewhere a range containing formulas for instance, before placing that range in an array, that sheet **must** be calculated...